# Geometric Brownian motion - is there a way to construct a Brownian Bridge?

Tags: python

I've been trying to construct a GBM process to model the ACWI stock price (and the VIX - which whilst not quite lognormal, is just about "normal" enough), which is reasonably easy (probably can be done more efficiently).  I might switch to using arrays and then convert to pandas dataframe after the event.

```
simulation = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date","ACWI_Close", "Simulation"])
simulation1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date","VIX_Close", "Simulation"])

for sim in range(0,1000): # Taking 1000 paths
    data = {"Date":base,"ACWI_Close":S0,"Simulation":sim}
    data1 = {"Date":base,"VIX_Close":V0, "Simulation":sim}
    simulation = simulation.append(data, ignore_index=True)
    simulation1 = simulation1.append(data1, ignore_index=True)    
    print(data)
    for day in dates:
        next_ACWI = simulation["ACWI_Close"].iloc[-1]*np.exp((mu-(sigma**2/2))+sigma*np.random.normal())
        next_VIX = simulation1["VIX_Close"].iloc[-1]*np.exp((mu1-(sigma1**2/2))+sigma1*np.random.normal())
        new_row = {"Date":day.to_pydatetime(),"ACWI_Close":next_ACWI, "Simulation":sim }
        simulation = simulation.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
        new_row = {"Date":day.to_pydatetime(),"VIX_Close":next_VIX, "Simulation":sim }        
        simulation1 = simulation1.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

However, this evidently gives a process which is GBM but has an open "future" end.

What I want to do is create a fixed number of paths ending at a particular point (say 1.1 x S0 - so market up 10% in the 109 days of my future period).  I can of course easily just create lots of paths and select the paths which end near my endpoint, but I would rather be more precise.

I've looked at using Brownian bridges for a regular process, but I cannot seem to get to a point where I can construct a Brownian bridge for a GBM process.

I've tried to construct a brownian bridge to provide my "w" values but evidently, just because these all end on the same point, the exponential may not...